# How to get list of all XML elements that are not defined in XSD file

Tags: java, xml, validation, xml-parsing, xsd

I have an XML and XSD file and am using a SAX parser to validate the XML file.
I want to find a list of all XML elements that are not defined in XSD file and vise versa.

**Test.xml**

```
<Records>
    <Record>
        <VendorID>Velos</VendorID>

        <PatID>M004</PatID>
        <aa></aa>
        <PatLName>LName2</PatLName>        
        <DOB>12/06/1902</DOB>
        <RecordID>R004</RecordID>   
        <ss></ss>
    </Record>
</Records>
```

**DummyXSD.xml**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
           xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
  <xs:element name="Records">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Record" type='recordType'/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>   

  <xs:complexType name="recordType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="VendorID"  type='xs:string'/>
      <xs:element name="PatID"     type='xs:string'/>      
      <xs:element name="PatLName"  type='xs:string'/>  
      <xs:element name="haveToInXml"  type='xs:string'/> 
    </xs:sequence> 
  </xs:complexType>   
</xs:schema>
```

**Java code:**

```
public class XmlValidator {
 public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
     try{   
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(new File("E:/Paw/Dendrite/Dendritep/TestData/dummyXSD.xsd"));
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);

        //using SAX Parser
        final SAXParserFactory saxFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        saxFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        saxFactory.setSchema(schema);           
        final SAXParser saxParser = saxFactory.newSAXParser();          
        CustomErrorHandler errorHandler =new CustomErrorHandler();                              
            saxParser.parse(new File("E:/Paw/Dendrite/Dendritep/TestData/Test.xml"), errorHandler); 
     }catch(SAXParseException e){
        System.out.println("in catch"); 
        System.out.println(e.getLineNumber() +"   "+e.getColumnNumber());
        System.out.println(e);
    } 
    catch (Exception e){
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
public class CustomErrorHandler extends DefaultHandler{
    final List<SAXParseException> exceptions = new LinkedList<SAXParseException>();
    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException e){ 
        System.out.println("In error");    
        exceptions.add(e);
        String err = e.toString();
        System.out.println(e);          
    }   
}
```

**Error message:**

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Rakesh%20Kumar/Desktop/Stack/Test.xml; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 7; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'aa'. One of '{PatLName}' is expected.
```

How can I get all elements that aren't defined in the XSD file?

This example output shows only `aa` element, but `ss` element also is not defined in the XSD.  How can I get the list of all elements that are missing in the XSD and vise versa?

Answer (score 0):

**To determine all of the elements in an XML document that do not appear in an XSD**, your plan is to leverage validation.  While this may at first seem to be a reasonable approach, the trouble is that trying to recover from parsing errors becomes increasingly complex as each error is encountered.  For this reason, the default is to halt after the first serious error.

You might try configuring the parser to continue after encountering an error.  Xerces2-J, for example, has a [**http://apache.org/xml/features/continue-after-fatal-error feature**](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html#continue-after-fatal-error) that will attempt to continue parsing after a fatal error.  You should probably heed their warning, however that

> The behavior of the parser when this feature is set to true is
>   **undetermined**!  Therefore use this feature with extreme caution because the parser may get stuck in an infinite loop or worse.

**It probably makes sense to re-examine the requirements and the approach.**  If only raw lists of elements are needed to be compared, perhaps you could create such lists by parsing the XML document (for elements) and the XSD (for `xs:element/@name` attributes) separately, and then comparing the lists.  Your requirements come into play here, though.  For example, here are just a few questions to consider:

- Is element appearance and not location/use all that matters?
- Do you have to handle `xs:import` and `xs:include` statements in the XSD?
- Can you use XSLT, or must you use SAX or some other way to build and compare the lists of elements?

Finally, if your actual goal is simply to make the XML document valid according to the XSD, the usual cycle would be to **fix each error as encountered and re-validate**.  In practice, not having a complete set of errors upfront does not end up being an issue when operating in this manner.